# What happens to a Titan Shifter if they die without being eaten?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The question is very vague, so let me clear up some of the confusion and haze.

In the entirety of AoT, it is known that, to inherit the powers of a Titan Shifter, the chosen one must eat the current holder, absorbing their spinal fluid as they do so, as is the curse of Ymir. But what happens to the Titan abilities should the current Titan Shifter be killed in different circumstances, besides being eaten by the Inheritor of said power?

What if the Titan Shifter is killed in combat by being blindsided on the battlefield, for instance? Or dies under mysterious circumstances? Is the power still retained by the holder's corpse, or does the power "drain" away when they die?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found in **Chapter 88**:

> [image]
>  [image]

Or, to quote [the wiki](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_the_Titans#cite_note-m88p23_.26_24-28):

> If an individual with the power of the Titans dies before it can be transferred, the power will be passed on to the first Baby among the *Subjects of Ymir*, who is born *directly after* the said inheritor's death, regardless of distance or relation to the previous inheritor.

---

As you can see,

> as long as there are Eldians remaining in the AoT world, the power of the Titans will never vanish.

Comment: Woah. Didn't expect an answer so quickly.

Comment: You're welcome :)