# Can the attack titan and the founding titan be splitted?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Currently Eren Jaeger has the power of the attack titan and the power of the founding titan. Can these titans be splitted again or are those 2 powers supposed to remain like this forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently two possible ways to inherit a titan's power:

- Injecting someone with Titan fluid and have him eat a Titan shifter
- Wait for the Titan shifter to die to have a random person inherit it

Going by the first scenario, the person with Titan fluid has to eat the person. It has never been proven or shown that eating just a portion would also grant a portion of the power so there is no way to know. As far as I know, *there is no precedent to someone holding more than one Titan power like Eren*, aside from Ymir (the first one), so there's also *no information as to how to split power from an Eldian holding two Titan shifter abilities*. Remember, too, that Eren inherited two Titan shifter abilities from his father (the power was never split).

For the second scenario, as mentioned [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49496/what-happens-to-a-titan-shifter-if-they-die-without-being-eaten), a baby will inherit a power of a previous Titan shifter who died due to the curse. It was never mentioned at all that a baby can inherit two Titan shifter abilities from someone wielding both, *only that one of the Titan's power would go to a baby born after the previous wielder's death*. (Notice that it's singular, not plural) This is seen in **Chapter 88**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be splitted as you when a titan holder dies their powers goes to a newly born child , so in this case when Eren dies then his each power will go to different children