# If Eren Jaeger dies without transfering his titan powers, will both powers transfer to the same child?

Tags: attack-on-titan

It's told in the story that if a titan shifter dies without transferring his power, this power will go to an eldian person who just was born. If Eren Jaeger dies without transferring his titan powers, will the attack titan and the founding titan go to different persons?

Note that his is not a duplicate of [What happens to a titan shifter if they die without being eaten](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49496/what-happens-to-a-titan-shifter-if-they-die-without-being-eaten) as this is not about what happens when a titan shifter dies. But what happens if a titan shifter with 2 powers dies, which is not answered in the answer.

Comment: Notice Eren's use of words (singular, not plural) in the quoted chapter in the link above and the explicit mention of one of the titan's power being inherited by a baby, which I think, fully answers this question.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate at all . The question linked asks what happen to a regular Titan shifter is he dies without being eaten. This question asks what happens to a Titan shifter who has 2 titan powers inside him, and how those 2 powers will be transfered. Will they go to the same born person? Will they go to 2 persons?

Comment: ATM, the manga has not addressed the issue. My personal guess is one child inherits all. But it is questionable where the knowledge with death and transference comes from at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think Yes.  According to the manga, if the host of the titan body dies, their power goes to the newly born child.
And since Eren has now acquired more than one titan's powers, then if Eren dies, then each of his powers will go to separate newly born children.
Here is a fandom theory if you would like to read... that can answer much of your questions[fandom theory](https://www.google.com/amp/s/survey-corps-potato.tumblr.com/post/164670567447/ending-theory/amp)

Warning : there might be some spoilers in the link, read only if you have read till current manga chapter